# Import an Excel file that has newline \n as string

Tags: r, excel, newline, r-rio

I have an Excel file and a cell which contains a newline.

```
1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,\n    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______
```

After I used the `rio` package to import the Excel file, I have a double backslash:

```
 df <- rio::import("excel_file.xlsx")

 print(df[1,])

"1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,\\n    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______"
```

I would like to import the string as \n without have to use the `gsub`/`sub` function, I tried to change the line into:

```
1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,'\n'    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______
1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,/n    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______
1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,\\n    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______
```

but it didn't work.

My desired output is to have \n after running `rio::import`:

```
"1. , : Yes, number of years: ______,\n    : Year at which exposure stopped: _______"
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Try `cat(myString)`, do you still see the extra backslash?

Comment: `"I used rio package"` please share the code.,

Comment: does the initial file actually have a newline, or just the characters "\n"? Because the double backslashes seems to indicate that it is an escaped backslash. I created [a spreadsheet with a newline in a cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DDiBQwP2DzHi3rC51sBhWIl7E71s58ZK5iwsgymWVmA/edit?usp=sharing), and after importing with ```rio``` I got ```[1] Hello\nWorld!                                         
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)```

Comment: @MarkHill it only marks \n, I tried to rio::export it into excel to check, it becomes a newline in excel, not a character, but in my initial excel file, it is the character \n.

Comment: How odd! So, from what I gather, the gist of the problem is that the spreadsheet you have, when imported, gives you something with a ```\\n```, when you would prefer ```\n``` (feel free to correct me)

Right now, it's unclear where the issue lies. I'm assuming because I was able to make a spreadsheet with only one backslash, the issue is not with R or rio in general. 

Could you upload the file? If the issue can be replicated on someone else's computer, the issue is with rio, or the file. If not, it's something with your install of rio